# GWT tool is not loading in Chrome browser of Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, google-chrome-os, sakai

I am using Gradebook2 for Sakai, developed using GWT. This tool is not loading in Chrome browser of Chrome OS. As per [GWT Website](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/FAQ_GettingStarted.html) there is no support for Chrome OS (supports Windows Vista/XP/2000, Mac OS X 10.4+ (Tiger or Leopard), or Linux with GTK+ 2.2.1+).
Below dependencies are configured in pom.xml

```
    <properties>
        <gb2.version>1.9.0</gb2.version>
        <gxt.version>2.2.5-gwt22</gxt.version>
        <gxt3.version>3.0.1</gxt3.version>
        <gwt.version>2.5.0</gwt.version>
        <!-- following fix for bug in gwt 2.3.0 poms (should've been included in those but were not) -->
        <javax.validation.version>1.0.0.GA</javax.validation.version>
        <gb2.commons.logging.version>1.0.4</gb2.commons.logging.version>
        <gb2.jackson.version>1.9.9</gb2.jackson.version> 
        <gb2.jersey.version>1.13</gb2.jersey.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Please use the Chrome browser inspect mode and report back any errors from the console.

Comment: These requirements are for the development environment (and are awfully outdated!), not the runtime environment. Read lower in the page for browser support.

Comment: @samottenhoff no errors on console.Opened sakai JIRA ticket [GRBK-1432](https://jira.sakaiproject.org/browse/GRBK-1432)

Comment: @ThomasBroyer As per GWT website, it supports Google chrome. I can access the tool successfully from chrome on Windows but not from chrome on Chrome OS.